# Products distribution planning model

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, modeling, constraint

I have a problem of planning the distribution of products for a month. I have different unique products. A Mandate is provided for each product, and the Mandated quantity for each product is to be delivered during the month while respecting stock levels (cant deliver it all directly cause no stock available). Products are delivered through loading stations to vehicles. I need to minimize the number of vehicles used. I have developed the following model but for some reason variable $B$ seeks always to be positive, rendering the problem sometimes infeasible or giving erroneous results. Can anyone help me with catching the issue, any help is very much appreciated. Even if it is some reference to close problem in the literature.

Variables:

$x_{p,t,j}$ continuous variable representing the quantity of product $p$ to be delivered on day $t$ using station $j$

$S_{p,t}$ quantity of available stock of product $p$ at day $t$

$B_{p,t,j}$ boolean variable equal to 1 if product $p$ is scheduled to be delivered on day $t$ using station $j$

$Y_{t,j}$  boolean variable equal to 1 if station $j$ is open on day $t$

Objective function:
$$
min \sum_p \sum_t \sum_j B_{p,t,j}
$$
Minimize the number of times a product is delivered

Constraints:

$$
(1) \sum_t \sum_j x_{p,t,j} = Mandate_p, \forall p
$$
$$
(2) S_{p,t} = S_{p,t-1} + Feed_{p,t} - \sum_j x_{p,t,j}, \forall p,t
$$
$$
(3) Min_{p} \le S_{p,t} \le Max_{p}, \forall p, t
$$
$$
(4)x_{p,t,j} \le M * B_{p,t,j}, \forall p,t,j
$$
$$
(5) \sum_j B_{p,t,j} \le 1, \forall p,t
$$
$$
(6)  B_{p,t,j} \le Y_{t,j}, \forall p,t,j
$$
$$
(7) \sum_p \gamma * x_{p,t,j} \le 24 * Y_{t,j}, \forall t,j 
$$
Constraint (1) is to assure Mandates are fulfilled for all products, constraint (2) is the stock level at time $t$, constraint (3) fixes the maximum and minimum allowable stock per product $p$, constraint (4) is a fixed-charge model that says that a product is delivered only if it is assigned to a station $j$, constraint (5) only one station is used for a product per day, constraint (6) a product $p$ is delivered at station $j$ if station $j$ is open at time $t$, constraint (7) is to model the time needed to charge multiple product which needs to be less than 24 hours, and it is allowed in case station $j$ is open. $\gamma$ is a constant representing speed.

Comment: Does \gamma stand for the product recharge unitary time? Can you give some short instance examples presenting infeasibility and, what you called, erroneous?

Comment: Thank you, yes \gamma is unitary, it is  0.004 for example, so if I have 1000 tonnes of product, it would need 1000*0.004=4 hours. As for intances, I can't find small instances where this is a problem, its is only when I plug the real problem. Maybe the problem is in the way I modelled the relationship between Y and B variables.

Comment: I think about it as a bin packing problem with continuous variable, but couldn't find anything like it on the internet, maybe I am missing something

Comment: The presence of $Y_{t,j}$ in (7) is probably redundant (albeit harmless) since $Y_{t,j}=0 \implies B_{p,t,j} = 0 \implies x_{p,t,j} = 0$ using (6) and (4). In any case, I don't see anything in the model to discourage the solver from setting $Y_{t,j}=1\,\forall t,j$.

Comment: Do you have any problem instances that are known to be feasible but make the model infeasible?

Comment: @MarcM, as I and prubin asked, a feasible instance, that the model considers as infeasible, would be very helpful to catch this bug.

Comment: @MarcM, the problem you are looking for is a variant of the `lot-sizing problem`. some of the good references could be found [here](https://alfresco.uclouvain.be/alfresco/service/guest/streamDownload/workspace/SpacesStore/4dce5c30-1e35-41c5-baca-b42944c9d588/coredp_2000_09.pdf?a=true&guest=true) and [here](https://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/pdf/10.1287/mnsc.47.7.993.9800).

Comment: Besides the other comments, the constraint $(3)$ might be omitted if the $Min_p$ and $Max_p$ are constants and can be represented as a $LB$ and $UB$ on the variable $S_{p,t}$. About the last constraint please, be sure that the summation of $\gamma$'s for all products has been less equal than the available capacity ($24$). Did you assert that?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers! @prubin the problem becomes infeasible when I use it on big instances, I am trying to narrow down the instances by removing products and resolving the model until I find the particular product(s) that makes it infeasible. For $Y$ variable, yes it is always one, but I wanted to be able to close some stations( for to maintenance for example) for some days, in this case I force $Y$ to be equal to zero.

Comment: @A.Omidi thanks for your answer! Yes I changed the lower and upper bounds of S, thank you for this observation, and also for the references, it is indeed a variant of the lot-sizing problem with demand $d$ variable. I did assert the sum of $\gamma$. What I mean by erroneous behavior of variable $B$  is that it is forced to take a value of $1$ even though its corresponding $x$ is equal to zero in the optimal solution.

Comment: @MarcM, thanks for the clarifying. One thing is that, if you are interested to force the variable $B$ to be zero with respect to the variable $x$, re-write the forth constraint as: $B_{p,t,j} \leq x_{p,t,j}$. From what you mentioned, the variable $B$ can be valued if the variable $x$ would be zero. Would you check it?

Comment: @A.Omidi I tried it, the solver indicated  infeasible. I really can't see the reason why $B$ is forced to equal to 1. I double checked my implementation ( I use pyomo with CBC solver).

Comment: @A.Omidi i shall double check the instances and their feasibility and get back to share what I find

Comment: @MarcM, thanks. For checking the infeasibility, it would be possible to replace the current object function with a dummy objective equal to zero to check whether your model can produce a feasible solution. Another staff would be, as you said using Pyomo, this platform can be linked to the Neos server to use some of the state-of-the-art solvers like CPLEX, Gurobi, etc for using some of those advanced functions like `IIS` to compute which constraints cause the infeasibility.